# Downgrade Ubuntu for Gitlab

Tags: ubuntu, gitlab

I'm hosting Gitlab local on an Ubuntu server. 
Without checking if Gitlab was supported on the Ubuntu 18.04 version I've just installed it.

Now I've noticed that I can't update my Gitlab installation to the newest version. Gitlab is working correctly like before.

Is it possible to downgrade Ubuntu 18.04 to 16.04? Without any major problems? Or should I create a new Ubuntu server Ander install a backup of Gitlab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu does not support a upgrade roll back.

It is theoretical possible, but highly discouraged and will take much longer than simply back up the whole instance per CLI and then load the backup on the new server.

You can find a how-to [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/raketasks/backup_restore.md).

Comment: I thought so yet. Thank you for confirming.